# Is it possible to model a PIN InGasAS photodiode in a SPICE simulator?

Tags: simulation, photodiode, optoelectronics

I want to know if it is possible to model a InGasAs panchromatic PIN photodiode, in accord with datasheet, in simulator SPICE MicroCAP 12. Because the supplier doesn't provide a SPICE model. And if it is possible, which are those steps.

Here is data-sheet https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ig17x1000s4i/photodiodes/laser-components/ And below I will attach an electrical schematic of a transimpedance amplifier with phototdiode, used as a smoke receiver.

I want to monitor graphically the impulse of photodiode in function of output of transimpedance for sensibilty. I found a type of photodiode in the Micro-CAP 12 library but it is simple photodiode, which does not match the datasheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What will be your inputs to the photodiode and which photodiode specifically are you talking about?

Comment: Here is the datahseet https://www.tme.eu/Document/726cc5089c90f506f2d9a008ec28a891/ig17.pdf.  And I want to monitor graphically the signal output of amplifier in function of signal impulse at the input of photodiode, for to follow the sensibilty/responsivity.

Comment: And what form does the signal input take (bearing in mind that this is an electrical simulation package)?

Comment: The form it must be, an optical rectangular impulse.

Comment: Micro-cap works with signal inputs that are voltage and current.

Comment: What does it mean?Will that be impossible with this program to get those reults?

Comment: Of course it will work but you have to get your head around how you want to "drive" the photodiode using MC12? Read the data sheet and ask yourself what is the main "thing" that the diode produces electrically that is affected by light? Then read the data sheet some more and get the equation for that light to "something" relationship. That is the first step.

Comment: In fact the first step is READ the data sheet and state what specific diode you are talking about. I did ask you to do this 35 minutes ago and you seemed to have forgotten.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain some some satisfying results, if i follow this equivalent circuit, from this documentation? http://www.osioptoelectronics.com/application-notes/an-photodiode-parameters-characteristics.pdf  ?

Comment: I can't help you without a specific diode model and this is the third time of asking.

Comment: I am sorry, if i do not understand corectly, but I showed the datasheet of photodiode,I think this is a good reference.,And I must to create photodiode in accord with data sheet.I must follow the specific parameters of photodiode, from the datasheet.

Comment: You write English very well so I have to assume you can read a data sheet so, why can't you supply the specific part number of the device. Just read the data sheet and tell me which diode you are considering. I'm not going to ask again.

Comment: I am sorry.It is about the photodiode PIN with mounting THT, with case TO46.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can model a photodiode with a circuit in SPICE. And the circuit you linked will work.(figure 3 of : http://www.osioptoelectronics.com/application-notes/an-photodiode-parameters-characteristics.pdf)

But first, I suggest that you read that entire document to really understand what a photodiode does and how it works.

You don't seem to get that :

> Photodiodes operate by absorption
> of photons or charged particles and generate a flow of **current** in an
> external circuit, proportional to the incident power.

And this is in the first paragraph of the document you linked.

See also :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode where they have another equivalent circuit (easier to understand but far less detail)
- a very similar question : [Calculating photodiode current based on A/W for simulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57016/calculating-photodiode-current-based-on-a-w-for-simulation)
- another one : [Equivalent circuit of a photodiode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/379828/equivalent-circuit-of-a-photodiode)